# Creating Username from Text File

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, count

I just know I'm being a numpty with this, so bear with me. Have tried my best so far!

Reading lines from a text file with forenames and surnames (some with middle names) to generate a username that is a joined version of forename and any middle name. If there is a duplicate, we pull in the first letter from their surname. If still duplicates, we suffix 1, and start counting up from there for more duplicates - I just can't get this part to work!

```
usernames = []

for line in open('classlist.txt'):
  count = 0
  name = line.lower().split()
  surname = name[-1]
  username = ''.join(name[0:-1])
  username_w_surname = username + surname[0]
  username_w_surname_integer = username_w_surname + str(count)
  if username not in usernames:
    usernames.append(username)
  elif username in usernames:
    usernames.append(username_w_surname)
  elif username_w_surname in usernames:
    count = count + 1
    usernames.append(username_w_surname_integer)

for entry in usernames:
  print (entry)
```

Which is returning

```
max
katherine
annamarie
james
jamesp
jamesp
jamesb
```

But the second `jamesp` should be `jamesp1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first two clause:

```
if username not in usernames:
    usernames.append(username)
elif username in usernames:
    usernames.append(username_w_surname)
```

covers all possibilities, because username is either in usernames, or is not. Thus you will never enter the third block:

```
elif username_w_surname in usernames:
    count = count + 1
    usernames.append(username_w_surname_integer)
```

This should solve the problem:

```
  if username not in usernames:
    usernames.append(username)
  elif username_w_surname not in usernames:
    usernames.append(username_w_surname)
  else:
    count = count + 1
    usernames.append(username_w_surname_integer)
```

And an optimization tip to the end: instead of using a list to collect usernames, take a look at [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

Comment: Doh! I knew I was being a numpty! This is what you get for trying to learn python on naff all sleep!! Cheers  : )

Comment: Started with sets then went to dictionaries then lists after realising dicts were no good as unordered. It's been a real tour around the houses!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
usernames = []
for line in open('classlist.txt'):
  count = 1
  name = line.lower().split()
  surname = name[-1]
  username = ''.join(name[0:-1])
  username_w_surname = username + surname[0]
  username_w_surname_integer = username_w_surname + str(count)
  if username not in usernames:
        usernames.append(username)
  elif username in usernames:            
        if username_w_surname in usernames:
                    count = count + 1
                    usernames.append(username_w_surname_integer)
        else:
            usernames.append(username_w_surname)
for entry in usernames:
  print (entry)
```